# how can I change icon when the Parent group has been expanded to show its children

Tags: java, android, android-layout, expandablelistview

I have an expandable list view and I would like to change the icon from right facing arrow to down facing arrow when the parent group has been clicked  and children are shown . Currently when I click on the parent group to expand and show children the icon does not change from right arrow to down arrow it just remains as rigth arrow icon . This is what I have in my exapndable adaptor at the moment .

```
@Override
   public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      String headerTitle = getGroup(groupPosition).toString();
      if (convertView == null) {
         LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
               .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);



         ImageView arrowImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById (R.id.group_header_arrow);
         if (isExpanded) {
            arrowImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_down);
           (ApplicationContext.Activity.Resources.GetColor (Resource.Color.standard_blue));
         }


      }
      TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);

      lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);
      TextView Header = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);

      lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);
      return convertView;
   }
```

The XML for the group header

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:padding="8dp"
              android:background="#f4f4f4">


   <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/group_header_arrow"
      android:src="@drawable/arrow_right"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:paddingRight="10dp" />

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
      android:textSize="17dp"
      android:textColor="#388C2A" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this code in adapter class,

```
    final ExpandableListView mExpandableListView= (ExpandableListView) parent ;

    mExpandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            arrowImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_down);
        }
    });

    mExpandableListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
            arrowImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_left);
        }
    });

    if(mExpandableListView.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition))
    {
       arrowImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_down);
    }
    else
    {
       arrowImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_left);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_empty="true" android:drawable="@drawable/right_indicator"/>
<item android:state_expanded="true" android:drawable="@drawable/left_indicator" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/right_indicator" />
```

saved in Drawable,